# How can I be sure my app has the proper permissions when I distribute it?

Tags: ios, xcode, permissions, jailbreak, cydia

About two years ago, I ran into a problem where my app will crash immediately on start up and it turned out to be a permission error. I got a solution and I haven't had this problem lately. The problem came back with the latest release of my app. I gave my app proper permissions the same way I had since the problem first occurred. I installed the compiled app on my iPod Touch in /Applications, give it the proper permissions via SSH, make sure it runs on the iPod, the copy it back to my Mac, zip it up and submit it to the repo. I never had a problem with this method until now. Even if I give the app proper permissions on the Mac and then zip it up, the app still does not have the proper permissions after being zipped up. My question is how can I make sure my has the proper permissions so that it will run on the users device when I distribute it? Just to be clear, I'm not asking how to give the app execute permissions, I know how to do that.

Comment: Debian packages has `postinst` script just for that case. In it you can do pretty much anything you want - it could be bash script or even command line application.